# What is wrong with my functions

Tags: c++, function

I am rather new to c++ and am messing around with functions.
I can't seem to figure out why the following code isn't working, 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    movieOutput("Hello");

    return 0;
}

//This is just for a little extra versatility
int movieOutput(string movieName,int aTix = 0,int cTix = 0,float grPro = 0.0,float nePro = 0.0,float diPro = 0.0){

    //I don't understand whether I should declare the arguments inside the 
    //functions parameters or in the function body below.

    /*string movieName;
      int aTix = 0, cTix = 0;
      float grPro = 0.0, nePro = 0.0, diPro = 0.0;*/

    cout << "**********************Ticket Sales********************\n";
    cout << "Movie Name: \t\t" << movieName << endl;
    cout << "Adult Tickets Sold: \t\t" << aTix << endl;
    cout << "Child Tickets Sold: \t\t" << aTix << endl;
    cout << "Gross Box Office Profit: \t" << grPro << endl;
    cout << "Net Box Office Profit: \t" << nePro << endl;
    cout << "Amount Paid to the Distributor: \t" << diPro << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The build errors I'm getting

```
`Build:(compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)
|line-8|error: 'movieOutput' was not declared in this scope|
Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|`
```

Comment: Move the definition of main below the function used

Comment: as @JosephYoung suggests or write a forward declaration line for that function "above" the first function "calling" it (here main)

Comment: Thank you guys, you all helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a forward declaration of

```
int movieOutput(string movieName,int aTix = 0,int cTix = 0,
                float grPro = 0.0,float nePro = 0.0,float diPro = 0.0);
```

appearing before `main()`.

Also default parameters need to go in the function declaration not the definition signature.

Here's the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int movieOutput(string movieName,int aTix = 0,int cTix = 0,
                float grPro = 0.0,float nePro = 0.0,float diPro = 0.0);

int main() {
    movieOutput("Hello");

    return 0;
}

//This is just for a little extra versatility
int movieOutput(string movieName,int aTix,int cTix,float grPro,float nePro,float diPro){

    cout << "**********************Ticket Sales********************\n";
    cout << "Movie Name: \t\t" << movieName << endl;
    cout << "Adult Tickets Sold: \t\t" << aTix << endl;
    cout << "Child Tickets Sold: \t\t" << aTix << endl;
    cout << "Gross Box Office Profit: \t" << grPro << endl;
    cout << "Net Box Office Profit: \t" << nePro << endl;
    cout << "Amount Paid to the Distributor: \t" << diPro << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your function before calling it x)

```
int movieOutput(string, int, int, float, float, float); // function prototype 

int main()... 

int movieOutput(...) { /* declaration goes here */}
```

Or just simply put the whole function declaration before your main

Comment: There's still an issue with the default parameter values.